# Matlab Group Dates by Month and Year

Tags: matlab

I have a list of dates and I'm trying to group them together by month (all those that occur within the same month are together.

I'm currently using:

```
groups;
for event=events        
    name = datestr(event.date,'Ayyyymm');

    if ~isfield(groups,name)
        groups.(name) = EventGroup; 
    end

    groups.(name).add(transaction);

end
```

But this has three main problems:

1. I can't loop over the fields of the group
2. There's no way to sort the field names, so the dates are in order
3. It seems rather hacky

Is there a better way to perform this kind of grouping that will allow me to loop over all the groups?

N.B. EventGroup is a object which is essentially a wrapper for multiple Event objects and each event.date = output from datestr() for each event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To 1)

1. You can get the names using `fieldnames`. You can loop over that.
2. alternatively you can use `structfun`

### To 2)

1. you could sort before you add the events
2. after you built group add the fields in sorted order
3. you could make groups an object that will sort itself

### To 3)

working code is always nice code - so no need to worry ;)